# You can't do this in html/template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to determine if the list I sent is empty or not.. but I get this error

my code:

```
{% if {{all_puzzles|length}} = 0 %}
      <h4 style="text-align: center">No puzzles found :/<br>
      <a href="/create/" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Create a Puzzle</a></h4><br>
{% endif %}
```

Error:

```
Template error:
In template /Users/Jyby/Documents/gpsp/templates/mypuzzles.html, error at line 26
   Could not parse some characters: |{{all_puzzles||length}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
{% if all_puzzles|length = 0 %}
```

Alternatively you can also do:

```
{% if not all_puzzles|length %}
```

which effects the same condition.